# When did lecturers and teachers stop wearing academic gowns regularly?

Tags: academic-history, outward-appearance, academic-dress

In the English-speaking world, around when did academic gowns fall out of favour as everyday wear for lecturers and teachers?

Comment: This varies by place. Long ago most places in US. More recently in some places in UK. Cambridge, for example, though IIRC the "gowns" were perfunctory.

Comment: With respect to Cambridge, it depends whether you're talking about arts & humanities or STEM, daytime or evening, and faculty or students (grad students may fit OP's designation "teachers"), and that blurs it out to a period between about 1940 and 1970.  But I have neither enough detail nor clear enough sourcing to turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: on the day academia fell out of favour.